# Can we export Selected Row with Subquery using data pump

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g, oracle-11g

I am trying to export selected rowS from my database using SUBQUERY but I got error.

```
expdp directory=exp_data dumpfile=selected_row.dmp logfile=rows.log tables=sample,super query="where name IN (select name from azeem.sample where name like 'Ten');"

Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Tue Jan 12 21:58:37 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username: / as sysdba

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39035: Data filter SUBQUERY has already been specified.
```

Can we use subquery in datapump?

Comment: Depending on the Operating System it's possible that you need to escape the quotes. A more robust solution is to use a parameter file as in @JSapkota's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we use subquery in datapump?

Yes we can. The following example shows how to do it.

I have created a parameter file to get this job done. In my test case I have two tables namely `tbl1` and `tbl2` under `HR` schema. You may change the name of the schema as your requirements.

```
[oracle@testsrv Desktop]$ cat query.par
Directory=user_dir
DUMPFILE=select_row.dmp
logfile=rows.log
tables=hr.tbl1, hr.tbl2
Query=hr.tbl1:"where name IN (select name from hr.tbl2 where name like '%T%')"
```

Then I have used the following expdp command to accomplish the task.

```
[oracle@testsrv Desktop]$ expdp system/oracle parfile=query.par

Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Mon Mar 21 15:59:18 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  system/password parfile=query.par 
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 128 KB
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
. . exported "HR"."TBL1"                                     5 KB       0 rows
. . exported "HR"."TBL2"                                 5.007 KB       1 rows
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SYSTEM.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01 is:
  /home/oracle/Desktop/select_row.dmp
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at Mon Mar 21 16:00:05 2016 elapsed 0 00:00:41
```

Comment: can I do join inside of the query ? for example "where not exists (select 1 from hr.tbl2 a where name=a.name )" can be this done?